# Q_ENUMS and using declarations do not work together

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, using-declaration

Consider the following class definition:

```
// exported.hpp

#include <QObject>

class Exported: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    enum class FOO { BAR };
    Q_ENUM(FOO)
};
```

And the following `main` file:

```
// main.cpp

#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "exported.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    qmlRegisterType<Exported>("Package", 1, 0, "Exported");
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

By doing this, I can easily access the named constants of my enum in QML.
As an example:

```
// main.qml

import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import Package 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    Rectangle {
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log(Exported.BAR)
        }
    }
}
```

This works as long as the declaration of the enum is enclosed in the class.
As an example, if I change the class definition as shown below, it doesn't work anymore:

```
// exported.hpp

#include <QObject>

enum class FOO { BAR };

class Exported: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    using FOO = ::FOO;
    Q_ENUM(FOO)
};
```

Now, `Exported.BAR` in the QML file is `undefined`.

---

The most basic question is: why it doesn't work with *using declarations*?
Note that it works with forwarded declarations, as an example:

```
// exported.hpp

#include <QObject>

enum class FOO { BAR };

class Exported: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    enum class FOO;
    Q_ENUM(FOO)
    enum class FOO { BAR };
};
```

This is true to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_ENUM) of `Q_ENUM` actually (emphasis mine):

> This macro registers an enum type with the meta-object system. **It must be placed after the enum declaration** in a class that has the Q_OBJECT or the Q_GADGET macro.

No mentions of a definition in the whole section.
On the other side, we have this from the standard:

> A using-declaration introduces a set of declarations into the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears.

So, I was expecting it to work as well. Anyway, this was maybe a wrong expectation on my side.

That said, any suggestion on how to deal with such an inconvenient?
The only way I can see to work around it in case the *enum* is defined out of the class is to define another *enum* within the class and have a one-to-one mapping between them.
It's far from being maintainable and a bit tedious indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with standard C++, at least not directly. Qt's [moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html) is quite limited in its understanding of C++ syntax rules (and with good reason<sup>1</sup>). Apparently this way of importing enums into class scopes is outside of it's abilities.

In my code, when I want moc to generate enum <-> string conversions for me, I go with the alias, but in the opposite direction:

```
class Exported: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    using QObject::QObject;

    enum class FOO { BAR };

    Q_ENUM(FOO)
};

using FOO = Exported::Foo;
```

This keeps moc happy and is valid C++. The downside is that you pull up the definition of `Exported` into every scope you use `FOO`'s definition in, and you can't forward-declare `FOO`.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>it was created before libclang was a thing and the implementation cost of a full C++ parser for a few corner cases would be extremely uneconomical.</sub>

Comment: Well, the actual problem is that the enum comes from a library, so I cannot do this. Thank you anyway. Also, the reference to the standard was to refer to the fact that probably _declaration_ is missed in the Qt documentation. That's all.

Comment: @skypjack Okay, it's possible that Qt's docs could be improved. I'll leave this answer for posterity, even if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Absolutely, it is fine in the general case, if you have control both of the class and of the enum.

Comment: If you've got a .h from that library with just the enums defined in there, you could do `class Foo : public QObject { Q_OBJECT`, `#include <stuff.h>`, `Q_ENUM(MyEnum) };` ... not that I'm suggesting it ...